# Greaseproof paper

Tags: freezing

Is there any kind of greaseproof paper that is 100% wood pulp? I do not like using plastic as the first wrapping when preparing iced cakes to be frozen. Is there freezer paper that's just paper, no wax or plastic?

Answer (score 4):

What about parchment paper?  It can be found alongside plastic wrap and aluminum foil in most grocery stores and large retailers.
 P.S. Lining the bottom of cake pans with parchment before baking is perfect for removing the cake safely from the pan.

Comment: +1 for parchment but it *is* silicone impregnated paper. Is silicone ok for the OP or is does that sound too "chemically"? Perhaps if it were called "natural sand extract" instead of silicone?

Comment: @Sobachatina I'd never heard that parchment paper had silicone in it, and wikipedia doesn't say it does either: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchment_paper_(baking)

Comment: @Jefromi- look under the "Bakery release paper" heading in your wikipedia link. Thanks for the info though. I only knew about the silicone method not the sulfuric acid method.